# How do you get a MergedDictionary xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

Hi I need to modify at runtime a mergedDictionary.
I have

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <themes:LightTheme />
            <themes:DarkTheme />
            <globalStyles:Labels />
            <globalStyles:Controls />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

App.Xaml (I tried the following but always get null) but In debug I can see those dictionaries ..

```
  1. Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("LightTheme", out var lightTheme);
  2. var theStyle= Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContainsKey("DarkTheme"));
```

What Am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out how to do this

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.OfType().FirstOrDefault();